# VS Code & Node.js: Use console() instead of console.log()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, arcgis, console.log

I'm writing JavaScript expressions to be used in [specialized geospatial software](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/logic/).

In the geospatial software, only `console()` is valid, not `console.log()`.

---

As I'm working, I'm debugging my geospatial scripts in [VS Code using Node.JS](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcade-js-testing-in-vs-code-how-to-run-simple/m-p/1150508/highlight/true#M52348) (since the geospatial software doesn't have linting functionality, etc.).

It's my understanding that Node.js uses `console.log()` syntax, not `console()`.

Therefore, when moving the script back and forth between the two programs, I need to do a *find and replace* to switch from `console()` to `console.log()` (and vice versa). This is becoming tedious.

---

**Question:**

In VS Code / Node.js, is there a way to use `console()` instead of `console.log()`? That would make things a lot easier when developing my scripts. I'd be able to have a standard script that works in both programs.

*I'm a novice, so layman's terms would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In VS Code / Node.js, is there a way to use `console()` instead of `console.log()`?

I can't think of a way to do that that wouldn't potentially blow up code in other modules that you may be using, since it would require *reassigning* the `console` global, and that's...global. (I have included one possible option below, but...I don't like it.)

But even if you can find a way to do that, I wouldn't. Instead, at the top of the script, I'd have something like:

```
const log = typeof console === "function" ? console : console.log;
```

...and then use `log` (or whatever name you want to use) throughout the script. It'll refer to the appropriate function.

---

Here's something that **might** not blow up other code:

```
console = Object.assign(console.log, console);
```

That replaces `console` with `console.log`, but also puts all of the `console` properties (well, the own enumerable ones anyway) on the function as properties, so both `console` and `console.log` (and `console.error`, etc.) work. But there's no guarantee that code in an unsuspecting module doesn't do `if (typeof console === "object")` to decide whether it can use `console`, and that would fail because `typeof` would return `"function"` for it instead.

So again: I'd use the first solution above: A standalone `log` function.